# Pipe an email to a python script

Tags: python, email, pipe, cpanel

I've set up inside of my CPanel to have all emails sent to x@x.com to be piped into a python script of mine.  How would I go about having any attachments saved into a specific directory on the server and perhaps see the subject/message of the email itself?

Comment: The docs on the formatting of a forwarded email are not exactly, well, existing.  Does it give you a mutlipart message, some sort of stringified representation thereof, some path to the file on the server, or something else?  Unless @Thomas' answer works for you, it's hard to tell you how to process this data correctly when we can't find out how the data is formatted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`email`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html#module-email) package to process MIME-formatted email messages. Use [`email.parser.FeedParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html#feedparser-api) to parse the message and get back an [`email.message.Message`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html) object:

- Treat it like a dictionary to get header fields like `Subject`.
- Use `is_multipart()` to check whether it is multipart and therefore might have attachments (or it might just be a plain-text + HTML message).
- Use the `walk()` method to recursively walk over all multipart submessages. Submessages with a `Content-Disposition` header starting with `attachment` are attachments, and you can get their contents using `get_payload()`.

Comment: I found http://harrybailey.com/2009/02/send-or-pipe-an-email-to-a-php-script/ which has a comment that seems to suggest that messages come through as strings, so this should work, I think.